# lengthy page load time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page that takes 12 seconds to load  !

The page requires the display of 20 different items of data generated by SQL count queries.

There is no option to combine the queries since the SQL is different each time.

I have tried indexing the relevant tables but to no avail ...

I have also thought about implementing memcache and using page caching.

I am using the popular codeigniter php framework.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you can't batch the queries together?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: You should not vote a question down or up because of the questioner, but because of the question. (Of course this question also deserves the downvote because it is not well asked)

Comment: @Nobody perhaps you're right but still, I don't see a better tool to teach a person this lesson within StackOverflow's system - is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron that does the counting in command line while updating a seperate "counts" table.  So you'll have 20 entries in the counts table which you can all request in one single query.
During page load query only that table.

You can decide yourself how often the cron should run, but make sure it doesn't take too long or else just seperate the different count-update-process into different cron files (or commands).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's likely to be negligible, but how many fields are you actually returning on each COUNT() query? I've heard in the past that with COUNT(), you're actually better off using something like COUNT(*) than COUNT(columnname) because that way the database can base it on whatever column will be quickest.

Might also be worth looking at CodeIgniter's database caching class - this sounds like exactly the kind of situation where that would be useful.

CodeIgniter's Profiler class is really handy for anything like this. If you enable that and use the report it generates to get an idea of how long it's taking for each query, you may be able to optimise at least some of them.

Also, you might want to consider using a bytecode cache - APC is pretty good and seems to work well with CodeIgniter. As far as I know it won't speed up the actual database transactions, but it is likely to make the application faster by speeding up PHP execution.